# How do I stop Github changing my project name?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to create a new repository in Github, and I'm having trouble with it's name.  It's a C++ project, so I'd like to call it:

**superproject++**

However Github creates me a repo with a url of:

**git://github.com/alanw/superproject--.git**

which looks pretty bad.

Is this a constraint of Github or git itself?

---

I've played around with a few alternatives, but I'm not to keen on:

- **superprojectcpp**
- **superprojectpp**
- **superproject_cpp**
- **superprojectplusplus**

Any ideas?

Comment: +1 - I actually laughed out loud at git's sense of humor ;)

Comment: Would you be keen on `superproject%2b%2b`? :)

Comment: Perl modules have this problem, too.  Foo::Bar becomes Foo--Bar.  We usually use Foo-Bar now.  At least they don't force lower case any more.  How about super-project-action-force?

Comment: There was a recent patch in Git that fixed something about "+" in url, maybe Github hasn't taken it into account yet.

Answer (score 13):

The "plus" character often holds special meaning in URLs, and can't be used unencoded.  For instance, spaces are sometimes encoded with a '+', rather than the more unfriendly '%20'.  Assuming that git is doing this, you'll have to pick something else.  Sorry.

(**superprojectplusplus** isn't so bad)

Comment: I'm guessing it's not Git, but rather GitHub's server-side software, that is altering the name.

Comment: Yep, that seems likely, and what I meant to say.

Comment: I believe the newest version of git supports using + in url. There was a patch to fix gtk+'s repo.

Comment: yeah +'s in the URL isn't really a great idea IMO.